# How do I ensure multiple statements all return Some?

Tags: vector, rust, option-type

```rust
let message = tokens.pop().expect("rabl_server encountered login error #send_message()");
let target = tokens.pop().expect("rabl_server encountered login error #send_message()");
let sender = tokens.pop().expect("rabl_server encountered login error #send_message()");
```

Currently have this code right now that tries to pull a few elements from a vector (that I have already ensured has the proper number of elements) and am wondering if there is some standard way to achieve a similar result as the one above, and check that ALL operations returned Some at once, instead of essentially writing the same .expect() statement three times? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you have ensured that the vector has the right number of elements, which I take to mean you guarantee that the `pop()`s all return `Some(_)`. An alternative could be:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut tokens = vec!["1", "2", "3"];

    let mut i = tokens.drain(..3);
    match (i.next(), i.next(), i.next()) {
        (Some(message), Some(target), Some(sender)) => {
            println!("do something: {} {} {} ", message, target, sender);
        }
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}
```

`drain()` will panic if the range is not correct so this is ok to call unreachable.

Since you say you don't want to repeat `expect` I also assume you don't want to just repeat `unwrap()`. The above code minimizes repetition while also communicating that only `Some` will be returned.

If you don't need ownership you can use `as_slice()` and use slice pattern matching:

```rust
match tokens.drain(..3).as_slice() {
    [message, target, sender] => {
        println!("do something: {} {} {} ", message, target, sender);
    }
    _ => unreachable!(),
};
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: one could use itertools and collect tuple to also avoid repeat `Some()`

Comment: You should be careful about `tokens` state with this solution. F.e. in your example if `message` is `None`, then `tokens` will still hold both possible `target` and `sender`. In this solution all three tokens will be pop at once.